# How to search inside main dictionary

Tags: python

Below is a dictionary.

```
h={'PC2': ['02:02:02:02:02:02', '192.168.0.2', '200', {}], 
   'PC3': ['2', '3', '4', {}],      
   'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1', '200', {'192.168.0.2': ('02:02:02:02:02:02', 1390612124.431)}]}
```

Now I want to search for '192.168.0.2' only in the main dictionary(h) not inside nested dictionaries. Now if that thing('192.168.0.2')is found, I want to point out the location of corresponding key i.e.'PC2'.

'192.168.0.2' will be entered by user(input) so if he inputs '192.168.0.1', I should be pointing at 'PC1' then I will be accessing the third element(nested dictionary) of PC1 and saving something.

So to summarize:

User inputs just "IP" e.g.192.168.0.1
Then I need to locate the key associated with that IP e.g. PC1 
and then I will save something(tuple associated with that IP) at the third location(nested dictionary)
e.g if the host('PC1')

e.g h['PC1'][3] ['192.168.0.1'] = 'y', 'z'

Comment: What problem are you having?   Each value of the main dictionary is a list.   Why don't you just search in that list for something that matches your input IP address?   A dictionary does not look like an IP address, so you won't search in the nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [178]: h={'PC2': ['02:02:02:02:02:02', '192.168.0.2', '200', {}], 
     ...:    'PC3': ['2', '3', '4', {}],      
     ...:    'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1', '200', {'192.168.0.2': ('02:02:02:02:02:02', 1390612124.431)}]}

In [179]: needle='192.168.0.2'

In [180]: keys=[k for k in h if needle in h[k]]

In [181]: keys
Out[181]: ['PC2']
```

Comment: I just want string 'PC2' so that I can search for it..not in the list format you have printed

Comment: @user3209413 If you just want the first occurrence, just get it by `keys[0]` ;)